# HasA relationship best way to implement?

Tags: java

I have below classes.

### One.java

```
public class One implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6761261711393553478L;

  private String name;
  private String id;

  //public getters and setters

}
```

### Two.java

```
 public class Two implements Serializable{

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 5671261711393553478L;

      private String rawId;
      private String genericId;

      //public getters and setters

    }
```

### Three.java

```
public class Three  implements Serializable{

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1231261711393553478L;

      private String extension;
      private String shift;

      //public getters and setters

    }
```

### Container.java

```
public class Container implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2345261711393553478L;

  private One one;
  private Two two;
  private Three three;

  //public getters and setters


}
```

Now clients will populate Container.java using setters and getters. Do you suggest any changes? **Is my Has A implementation correct?** Do u suggest any changes?

Thanks!

Comment: what is it i don't even

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code and answers will be based on options - however try the code review site

Comment: `Container` has a `serialVersionUID` but does not implement `Serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your design is fine.

You are using *Composition*, which is an object-oriented concept for `has-a` relationships.

For convenience, you might also like to add a constructor for Container.java, like so:

```
public Container(One one, Two two, Three three) {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
    this.three = three;
}
```

Comment: vikingsteve, thnx for ur answer. can i have setters also after having the constructor like in ur answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what a `hasA` relationship means - `Container` **has** three members - a `One`, a `Two` and a `Three`.

The only minor correction I'd introduce is to change `Container` so it's also `Serializable`.

So instead of:

```
public class Container {
    ...
```

You should have

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
    ...
```